# can't upload text in my description column on my xampp database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to construct a database with xampp that includes images, description and contact
columns
I can only upload images but the description and contact columns are empty
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0):

show your coding then understand yor problem.